# Is the subscription of merge replication only for SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-compact

While creating a publication I saw this

[image]

Does this mean the subscribers can't be other editions of SQL Server but Compact?
Do other editions need to use Peer-to-Peer replication instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only means that if you are using SQL Server Compact edition, that this edition can only be a subscriber, not a publisher.

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172447(v=sql.105).aspx) is more information on setting up merge replication between Microsoft SQL Server and SQL Server Compact 3.5.

Here is an example of a different subscriber than SQL Server Compact edition, a blogpost which sets up a Merge replication using SQL Server 2012 as the publisher and SQL Server 2008 R2 as the subscriber:

[Merge Replication Step By Step](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17532/SQL-Server-Replication-Merge-Replication-type-step-by-step.html)